# Complex setup for GIT: fork from Github to Bitbucket, PUSH to Bitbucket only

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

I'm not a GIT expert so I need some help on this setup for a project I'm working on. So basically this is what I need:

1. Create a fork from Github to Bitbucket, how? this guarantees made `git pull` all the time to mantain CORE updated with latest changes from Github main project?
2. Allow to PUSH only to Bitbuket repository, is that possible? How?

I'm using SmartGit as main client but also have git command line.

Any help on this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Once you have created an empty BitBucket repo, you can

```
git clone https://github.com/user/yourRepo
cd repo
git remote rename origin upstream
git remote add origin https://yourAccount@bitbucket.org/yourAccount/yourRepo
git push --mirror
```

Then make sure `master` will pull from the `bitbucket` repo (`upstream` being the name of the remote referring to the original GitHub repo)

```
git checkout master
git branch -u origin/master
git push.default matching
```

The `git push` will push to the bitbucket repo (`origin`), but you need `git pull upstream` to pull/update from the original GitHub repo.

By default, you will be working with the BitBucket one (like all other developers cloning that new repo), but a developer can add at any moment a reference (remote) to the original GitHub repo.

Comment: This approach will not work since there are others developers working with me and they need to pull from Bitbucket repo also, the idea is to mantain updated the Bitbucket repo from Github repo but made pull from Bitbucket repos. If you don't understand let me know and I build a simple diagram to illustrate what I need

Comment: @ReynierPM Ok, it is even easier then. I have edited the answer.

Comment: @VonC mirror error on your answer it's "git remote add origin..."

Comment: @psk Thank you. I have edited the answer accordingly.